# get item by id API getway AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS and I just created a API getway. I want to be able to get all the items in the DB and get a single item.

**Right now my  http Request to get ALL the items looks like this:**

```
https://xxxx.amazonaws.com/test/
```

I want to have something like this:

```
  https://xxxx.amazonaws.com/test/123
```

Where **123** is the value of a column called **RACF** in my DynamoDB database.

**My lambda function looks like this:**

```
   .
   .
   .
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
        const tableName = 'test';

        const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
            statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
            body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        });

        switch (event.httpMethod) {
            .
            .
            case 'GET':
                dynamo.scan({ TableName: tableName }, done);
                break;
           .
           .
           default:
                done(new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`));
        }
    };
```

I read I have to use the .  `dynamo.getItem()`. but I'm not sure how to implement it with the `GET`

> NOTE: I'm not using the command line. I'm using the AWS console on
>   their website with the nice UI.

GET CONFIGURATION:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add new resource to AWS API Getway, so you need to create `/test/{item_id}` path after that you need to create new method GET for the resource (You do all of it in AWS Apigateway under the APIs -> your api name -> Resources) and just point it to the same lambda function. Now you can get the `item_id` value from `event.pathParameters.item_id`. At the end you need to change your code to look more less like this

```
   .
   .
   .
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
        const tableName = 'test';

        const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
            statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
            body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        });

        switch (event.httpMethod) {
            .
            .
            case 'GET':
                if (event.pathParameters.item_id != undefined) {
                   dynamo.getItem({ 
                      TableName: tableName, 
                      Key: { 
                        id: { N: event.pathParameters.item_id } 
                      } 
                   },
                   done);
                } else {
                   dynamo.scan({ TableName: tableName }, done);
                }
                break;
           .
           .
           default:
                done(new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`));
        }
    };
```